# Is there any way to prevent screen shot and screen record of a flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to develop an App which need high security, and user can't take a screenshot or record a video from app, these are a very important features for my app. How do I need to do in a Flutter app to call the native code, or how to prevent these from native code?

Comment: You can try this, may be this will help: [screenshot flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/screenshot)

Comment: Have you also considered that the user might mirror the screen on a computer e.g. with droid@screen, use HDMI output or Miracast and somehow with these methods be able to capture the screen anyway? Or maybe run the app in a virtual Android device and record with the host OS? Or just point a camera at the device screen and capture?

Comment: I just consider on the phone, don't need to consider these situations you mentioned above.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent screen shot or screen recording, especially for those China branded Android phones such as Huawei and Xiaomi with screen recording app as 'system provided tools', they can start recording by simply 'knocking on the screen'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS there simply isn't a way to prevent screenshots / capture, you can only detect when a screenshot has already been made (like Snapchat).

On Android you could use the Display flag `FLAG_SECURE` (more about that here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE).
Mind that this won't prevent all possibilities of screen capture as @Markus Kaupinnen pointed out in the comments of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I can try what you said.